# Spotify API get track info based on track name?

Tags: api, spotify, libspotify, echonest, spotify-desktop

Is there a way to query the spotify API in order to get information about a `track/artist/album/playlist` based on its name.

E.g. query for `track=I need a hero&artistName=...` and get a `URI/ID` and some information about the track.

I couldn't find anything like this in the documentation. Am I overlooking something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [search API endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/), by specifying an artist and a track parameters, then extract the track ID from the response if there is only one match:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track:I%20need%20a hero%20artist:the%20artist&type=track"
```